# [Homework]Solving the recurrence t(n)=t(n/2)+n^2 using the iteration method

Tags: recurrence

Any hints on how to solve `t(n) = t(n/2) + n^2` with the iteration method? What I've got so far:

[image: My incomplete solution]

Comment: Asked the question here instead:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530285/solving-the-recurrence-tn-tn-2n2-using-the-iteration-method